# D3 Donut with new data will not draw properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I'm struggling to update my donut chart with new data.

When the data is swapped, the calculated segments are wrong. At first glance the chart might look like a proper donut, but if you inspect the donut you will see that one of the segments is the size of the entire donut.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LaserDeathBlade/Lb2temc8/)

I included a commented line of code that completely redraws the donut chart. If you uncomment it, you'll be able to see how the chart is supposed to look.

**The update function:**

```
function updateDonut(selector, dataset){
  var width = 120;
  var height = 120;
  var donutWidth = 25;
  var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  var color = d3.scale.category20c(); 

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .sort(null);

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
  .outerRadius(radius);

  var svg = d3.select(selector).select("svg > g");

  if(svg.empty()){
    svg = d3.select(selector)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
  }

  /*Uncommenting below line shows donut should look like*/
  //svg.selectAll("path").remove();

  var path = svg.selectAll("path");
  path = path.data(pie(dataset));

  path.enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i) })
    .attr("d", arc)

  path.exit().remove()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you switch dataset, you either need to remove the existing svg structure or reset them. You can remove them like this and the remaining code will create a new structure:

```
if(d3.select(selector))
d3.select(selector).select("svg").remove();
```

Here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swevens/Lb2temc8/17/